# Eclipse 2021-06 CDT GLFW vulkan app doesnt launch from within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-cdt, glfw, vulkan

I just started to learn vulkan but I cannot run or debug my app from within Eclipse.

What am I missing here?

Note: If I copy GLFW dll into my `app.exe` folder it starts correctly.

I am using Win10 64 bits, mingw64, vulkan sdk 1.2.189.0, glfw 3.3.4 win64 (precompiled) and glm.

My Eclipse 2021-06 config:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution to my problem. I just have to copy post build the dll file to the .exe folder.

to do this I went to "Project-> properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings"
under Build step tab, in Post-build steps command input box put the command.
(to copy I used "cmd /c copy path/to/file  dst/folder/path" )